# Am I eligible to contribute to Roth IRA in 2015

Tags: united-states, roth-ira, retirement-plan

I had a question with regards to the ability to contribute to Roth IRA. My current scenario is

1. I had a 401K with my previous employer ( in 2014. no contributions made since. I have not rolled it over to an IRA)
2. I have contributed the maximum amount for a HSA plan (3500 for 2015)
3. My income in 2015 will be <116K.

   Am I allowed to make contributions into a Roth IRA account? Or is all this based on my tax filings during the year 2014?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert, but [it looks like you can contribute the full $5,500 for 2015](http://www.rothira.com/roth-ira-limits) or $6,500 if you're age 50+ (or up to your earned income if it's less than the limit; you can't contribute more than you've earned).

If you were making more than $116k it might help bring down your AGI to make contributions to your 401k, but otherwise it won't affect this question. Even rolling over wouldn't affect your ability to make a contribution.

HSA contributions can also reduce your AGI, but again not needed here and otherwise don't affect your eligibility.

Comment: If somebody will be close to the limit there i one advantage the IRA or Roth IRA has: you can make a 2015 contribution in early 2016 after all the numbers are known.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep great point. One has until tax day of the following year to contribute to the current year's IRA.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep If you know you want to contribute to a Roth in that situation and you have no funds in av traditional IRA you can also opt for a back door Roth contribution.

Comment: Again waiting until January when the numbers are close, does allow you to know what to do.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep There's no need to wait until January for the backdoor Roth contribution.